# Advection term for a matrix equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, calculus

How can I calculate a quantity like

$(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) M$

where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity vector, and $M$ is some 3x3 matrix? (if one wants, assume $M$ is a tensor) This would be the advective term in a matrix equation that involves the material derivative. Further, how does one calculate this in cylindrical coordinates? An advective term like

$(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{c}$

where $\vec{c}$ is a vector makes sense to me, calculating one specifically for a matrix is throwing me off.

Comment: Related : [Nabla commutation in electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/683732/nabla-commutation-in-electromagnetism/683739#683739).

Comment: May be :
\begin{equation}
\left[\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon\cdot\nabla}\right)\mathbf M\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\right]_{ij}=\boldsymbol{\upsilon\cdot\nabla}\mathrm M_{ij}
\tag{A}\label{A}    
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the correct answer for all interested:

If we represent $M$ in cylindrical coordinates as

$M = M_{rr}(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{r}) + M_{r\phi}(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{\phi}) + M_{rz}(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{z}) + ...$

where $M_{rr} = M_{rr}(r,\phi,z)$, and similar for $M_{r\phi}, M_{rz},$ etc., then one can use the relation

$(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)f(r,\phi,z) = v_{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{v_{\phi}}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} + v_{z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$

and

$(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\vec{u} = [(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)u_{r}-\frac{v_{\phi}u_{\phi}}{r}]\hat{r} + [(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)u_{\phi}+\frac{v_{\phi}u_{r}}{r}]\hat{\phi} + [(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)u_{z}]\hat{z}$

where $u_{r} = \vec{u}(r,\phi,z) \cdot \hat{r}$ and the same for $u_{\phi},u_{z}$ to calculate directly

$(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)M = (\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)[M_{rr}(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{r}) + M_{r\phi}(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{\phi}) + ...] = ((\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)M_{rr})(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{r}) + M_{rr}((\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)(\hat{r} \otimes \hat{r})) + ...$